# How to add outbound in Piranha cms menu

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm nearly embarresed to ask this question, but I have searched/tryed with no luck.
How do I add an outbound link to a menu item in the manager? I just want one of my menu items to have an external link.
Best regards
Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each page type you can enable the option for pages to specify a redirect URL (like an outbound link). This gives you the option to either just enable it for all page types or to create a specific page type that handles redirects.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks a lot - that worked. I made myself a pagetype called external link and choosing this type in the menu gives the option to enter the url. It seem like you can't change the standard page to accept redirect urls. It gives an error.